# How do I set up the wiring for a SPX-18572 and Arduino Leonardo to use LoRa?

Tags: arduino, communication, lora

I was trying to find a guide to use the [SparkX LoRa SPX-18572](https://core-electronics.com.au/lora-1w-breakout-915m30s.html) with an Arduino Leonardo, but I could not find any guides to using these technologies online.

I'm hoping someone on here knows how to use this thing, as I can't figure out how it works.

How do I connect these two with a breadboard? What code is used to send basic data, and is there anything else I need to receive that data?

I can answer any questions about my setup and ultimate goal, but for now I am just looking for a way to make an array of 2-3 string data items send between two Arduino Leonardos. Thanks!

[image: SparkX LoRa]